# Getting Checked Radio Button in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

This question has been asked and answered before here but the code is not working for me. The purpose of this script is to either generate two form fields for height in feet & inches or a single one for centimeters based on the value the users selects via radio buttons.

I have the following HTML for two radio buttons:

```
<form id="post">
   <span id="select_height_unit" style="margin-right: 10px;">Unit of Measure: </span>
   <input type="radio" name="height_unit" value="ft" checked />Feet
   <input type="radio" name="height_unit" value="cm" />Centimeters
</form>
```

To test this I have the following jQuery:

```
(function ($) {
     console.log( $('input[name=height_unit]:checked', '#post').val() );
})(jQuery);
```

The result in the console is that `$('input[name=height_unit]:checked', '#post').val()` is undefined. I tried this both with and without the scope of `#post` and get the same result both ways.

Comment: works for me https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdNpqG

Comment: Chrome's console still reports it's "undefined" though.

Comment: Well you don't have a `value` attribute. But it's giving me "on" http://i.imgur.com/28BTxY8.png and if I specify a `value` on the tag, it reports the value http://i.imgur.com/ingu1sx.png

Comment: your updated code works, too https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/Emzobj

Comment: Added `value` attributes. Chrome's console is still reporting it as `undefined`. Firefox DE as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// For this to work the respective <script> should be placed before the closing
// </body> tag, otherwise...
(function ($) {
    // does not means DOM is ready! It's just an IIFE passing jQuery as argument
})(jQuery);
```

instead:

```
(function ($) {

    $(function(){
       // DOM is now ready!!
       // jQuery code here  
    });

})(jQuery);
```

It makes no sense to have two radio `input`s with no `value` attribute. How can you differentiate the received data otherwise?

So or in your specific case, adding everything that's needed:

```js
(function ($) {

    $(function(){
        
       function getUnit() {
          var unit = $('input[name=height_unit]:checked').val();
          console.log( unit );
          return  unit;
       }
       
       getUnit(); // Get on DOM ready
       $("[name=height_unit]").on("change", getUnit); // and on change

    });

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="post">
   <span id="select_height_unit" style="margin-right: 10px;">Unit of Measure:</span>
   
   <!-- For better UX use <label> -->
   
   <label><input type="radio" name="height_unit" value="ft" checked />Feet</label>
   <label><input type="radio" name="height_unit" value="cm" />Centimeters</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you. It's been a while since I worked with jQuery and such so I knew I had to be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log('Value is: ' + $('input[name=height_unit]:checked').val() );

//Below will get executed when you click on radio button
$('input[name=height_unit]').on('change', function(){
  console.log('New value is: ' + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="post">
   <span id="select_height_unit" style="margin-right: 10px;">Unit of Measure: </span>
   <input type="radio" name="height_unit" checked value='Feet' />Feet
   <input type="radio" name="height_unit" value='Centimeters' />Centimeters
</form>
```

Comment: A downvote should always be complimented with comment, so that one can learn and understand it better.

Comment: I voted you up because you actually helped me with the next step. And I agree with your sentiment.

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs doesn't have ***value*** attribute, so `.val()` cannot return any value.

```
<form id="post">
   <span id="select_height_unit" style="margin-right: 10px;">Unit of Measure: </span>
   <input type="radio" name="height_unit" value="feet" checked />Feet
   <input type="radio" name="height_unit" value="centimeters" />Centimeters
</form>
```

In your script you can select input with following selector. You selected two item by adding `'#post'` to jQuery selector.

```
(function ($) {
     console.log( $('#post input[name="height_unit"]:checked').val() );
})(jQuery);
```